# Error with tkinter Create and Move

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Im having a bit of a problem with my project. My game is running fine but we're not allowed to have errors in our shell. I have created a game where balloons come flying at you and you have to pop them with an arrow controlled by the keyboard.

My tkinter is throwing out a TclError with Invalid Command Name when I use move and create.

Here is my coding:

```
#Add balloons to the canvas and make them fly
import random

balloon_id = list()
balloon_radius = list()
balloon_speed = list()
MIN_BALLOON_RADIUS = 10
MAX_BALLOON_RADIUS = 30
MAX_BALLOON_SPEED = 10
GAP = 100

def create_balloon():
x = WIDTH + GAP
y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT)
r = random.randint(MIN_BALLOON_RADIUS, MAX_BALLOON_RADIUS)
id1 = c.create_oval(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r, outline='purple4', fill='MediumPurple2')
balloon_id.append(id1)
balloon_radius.append(r)
balloon_speed.append(random.randint(1, MAX_BALLOON_SPEED))

def move_balloons():
for i in range(len(balloon_id)):
    c.move(balloon_id[i], -balloon_speed[i], 0)
```

It throws out these errors for create_balloon():

```
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2334, in create_oval
return self._create('oval', args, kw)

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2319, in _create
*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".55505712"
```

And this error for move_balloon():

```
File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Varsity\xxx\Balloon Killer - 19342306.py", line 128, in <module>
move_balloons()
File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Varsity\xxx\Balloon Killer - 19342306.py", line 66, in move_balloons
c.move(balloon_id[i], -balloon_speed[i], 0)
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2430, in move
self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".42332976"
```

Comment: There is no relationship between the error message and the code you shared

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.  It would be in the code not posted, i.e.  1) did you create a Tk() instance 2) is there a mainloop called 3) is "c" a Canvas object  4) has "c" been added to the Tk() instance via grid, pack, or place 5) do you call create_balloon() at least once 6) same for move_balloons() 7) are the constants declared somewhere (WIDTH & HEIGHT).

Comment: I've added everything that you said needed to be added: I'll update my post with all my coding and I'll let you review it